# Get query from sqlite3_stmt of SQLite in c/cpp

Tags: c++, c, sqlite

I am using SQLite database with c/cpp and sqlite3 library from https://www.sqlite.org/index.html. For debugging purpose I want to print actual query from either sqlite3_stmt*  or sqlite3* object. How can i do that?